# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Javascript

Tags: javascript

So my program is supposed to do what the retro DVD logo used to do when it bounces around the screen and everyone hopes it hits the corner, but with a picture instead of a the DVD logo. I've been getting the error message mentioned in the title and it's been really frustrating to deal with.

my HTML code is:

```
<img id = "image" onclick="main()" onmouseover="imgRotation()" onmouseout="backNormal()" src= *image source* alt="PlayCode logo">

<canvas id = "tv-screen">
</canvas>
```

and my JavaScript code is:

```
var dvd = {
  x: 200,
  y: 300,
  xspeed: 10,
  yspeed: 10,
  img: document.getElementById("image")}
var canvas = document.getElementById("tv-screen");
var speed = 20;
var scale = 0.50;

function main(){
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    update();
}
function update() {
        dvd.x+=dvd.xspeed
        dvd.y+=dvd.yspeed
        checkHitBox();
        update();
    }

function checkHitBox(){
    if(dvd.x+dvd.img.width*scale >= canvas.width || dvd.x <= 0){
        dvd.xspeed *= -1;

    }

    if (dvd.y+dvd.img.height*scale >= canvas.hfeight || dvd.y <= 0){
        dvd.yspeed *= -1;
    }
```

Comment: Calling recursive function without exit condition.

Comment: Check `update();`.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it's pretty clear that you have a recursive call from your `update` function

```
function update() {
        dvd.x+=dvd.xspeed
        dvd.y+=dvd.yspeed
        checkHitBox();
        update(); // recursive call
    }
```

Maybe you want to try a timeout

```
function update() {
        dvd.x+=dvd.xspeed
        dvd.y+=dvd.yspeed
        checkHitBox();
        setTimeout(update, 100) // every 100ms
    }
```

Or simply use a fixed interval instead?

```
 function update() {
        dvd.x+=dvd.xspeed
        dvd.y+=dvd.yspeed
        checkHitBox();
    }
setInterval(update, 100);
```